# Sonata admin bundle: order entity field in showMapper

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

I'm searching for the solution in a development within a Symfony project with Sonata admin bundle.

2 entities: Contacts and Tags (ManyToMany Relationship)

Within the showaction of the sonata admin (tags entity), I'm unable to order the contacts field.  It does not matter if I use the query option within the field or not.  I used the query option in the create form, there the query works very well and the items are sorted in the select field.

This works (create form)

```
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $TagsQuery = $this->modelManager

        ->getEntityManager('TelRegBundle:Tags')
        ->createQuery(
            'SELECT t
             FROM TelRegBundle:Tags t
             ORDER BY t.title ASC'
        );       

    $formMapper
          //...

            ->add('tags', 'sonata_type_model', array(
                'class' => 'TelRegBundle\Entity\Tags',                    
                'property' => 'title',
                'multiple' => true,
                'query' => $TagsQuery,
            ))
```

Where the same approach does not work (show action):

```
    protected function configureShowFields(ShowMapper $showMapper)
{      

    $showMapper
        ->with('Tags data')
            ->add('title')
        ->end()
        ->with('Contacts')
            ->add('contacts', 'entity', array(
                'class' => 'TelRegBundle:Contacts',
                'associated_property' => 'title',

                'query' => ...  //Querybuilder not working.

                ))
        ->end()                
   ;
}
```

Anyone who can help?  Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only set [annotation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html)

```
/**
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Tags")
 * @OrderBy({"title" = "ASC"})
 */
private $tags;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try your suggestion

Comment: Ivan, this was the solution.   Live can often be so simple!  Many thx!